# symfony create & validate dynamic tabular

Tags: jquery, validation, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I want to create a dynamic tabular with input type text-field. After hitting the last row, one new row with a same input type text-field should be appear and the validation from the server side should also work. How can I do it? Is there any code example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about something like that?

[image]

Check [this article](http://www.thatsquality.com/articles/stretching-sfform-with-dynamic-elements-ajax-a-love-story).

**edit:**

It uses Propel, as you might noticed with the `TodoPeer`. So:

```
foreach(TodoPeer::doSelect(new Criteria()) as $todo)
{
  $todoWrapperForm->embedForm($todo->getId(), new TodoForm($todo));
}
```

Is just a basic `SELECT * FROM todo` to embed all todos form into the main one. With Doctrine:

```
$todos = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Todo')->findAll();
foreach($todos as $todo)
{
  $todoWrapperForm->embedForm($todo->getId(), new TodoForm($todo));
}
```

Comment: Do you know what might be TodoPeer? I don't get it.

Comment: TodoPeer comes from Propel. Check the [first tutorial](http://www.thatsquality.com/articles/can-the-symfony-forms-framework-be-domesticated-a-simple-todo-list), he uses Propel as Orm instead of Doctrine.

Comment: How should it looks like when I want to use Doctrine?